# How to get Custom Camera view with out using SurfaceView

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I want to develop customize camera application like [Snap chat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snapchat.android)!, with out using Surface view.

First i used surface view to develop the app,but i am unable get quality image and also i am unable to get all features what default camera app is providing, like Zoom, focus,face reorganization etc. Please provide me any solution to achieve this

sorry for my english

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are you looking for an example of a complete open-source camera app?

Comment: Actually, i tried with surfaceview, nd it is working fine. but i am unable to access all camera features. please suggest me, if any open-source camera app.

Answer (score 0):

github/xplodwild/android_packages_apps_Focal
github/almalence/OpenCamera
github/troop/FreeDCam
github/rexstjohn/UltimateAndroidCameraGuide

maybe one those might help